# In the Accelerate Framework is it safe to use the same reference for both input and output?

Tags: ios, accelerate-framework

I'm using the accelerate framework to create a fast vector and matrix library.  Is it safe to use the same float array as both an input and an output?  Is the code below safe?

```
Vec3f& Vec3f::operator+=(const Vec3f& rhs)
{
  // this->xyz is input and output.  Have I crossed the beams?
  vDSP_vadd(this->xyz, 1, rhs.xyz, 1, this->xyz, 1, 3);
  return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full answer to this question is a bit complicated, because the "Accelerate framework" is made up of lots of smaller libraries.  Broadly speaking, for "simple" vDSP functions (those that do work linear in their input buffers), like `vDSP_vadd`, yes it is safe to use the functions "in-place" (i.e. where one of the input buffers is also the output buffer).

However, I should point out that you don't want to use `vDSP_vadd` to add vectors of length 3.  That requires just three scalar operations, or a single vector operation; even the simplest scalar implementation will be done before you can even make the function call to `vDSP_vadd`.  What you're actually looking for is `<simd/simd.h>`, which contains SIMD implementations of small (2-, 3-, 4-dimension) vector and matrix arithmetic for iOS and OS X.  The operator overloads are already defined there for you, so you may not need to actually do much yourself:

```
#include <simd/simd.h>
using namespace simd;
float3 x = { 0, 1, 2 };
float3 y = { 1, 1, 1 };
float3 z = 2*x - y;
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit for using the **Accelerate Framework** is to capitalise on its ability to optimise against the **ARM** architecture.

> IMPORTANT: To achieve the best possible performance, the vDSP routines perform no error checking and return no completion codes. All arguments are assumed to be specified and passed correctly, and these responsibilities lie with the caller

For an in depth look at how it does this the [WWDC 2013 Session 713](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#713) is exceptionally informative.

Is the code below safe? - I'm not sure, however for optimal performance I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: For optimal performance, in place operation where possible is preferred. The number of alignment cases are reduced and less memory is used. Whether it works or not is regrettably undocumented for most vDSP.h functions.